# Hosting node server on heroku results in unexpected running of our game

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, phaser-framework

We hosted our game on heroku website.

The url of game is :https://ghost-wars.herokuapp.com/

and its source code is : https://github.com/Pradyuman7/GhostWars

While running the game on our pc, by writing

```
node server.js
```

we get our expected game, but while running the same game on heroku's website, the score increases sometimes by 150 or sometimes by 200 and also the new star location blips sometimes.

Please someone tell us how to resolve this issue because there are not many ways of deploying a node server online. We tried other sites too but same thing happened.

Thanks a lot for your time in advance.

Comment: Your question is way too broad, I doubt any users here will take the time to reverse engineer your whole repository to find a bug. Additionally, it's really hard to reproduce the issue, as it would require to create a Heroku app and everything. Please find ways to reduce your question to short code programming issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. But the code runs correctly on our pcs while it doesnt on online web hosting platforms. I dont think one needs to go through our codes.

Comment: Yes you wrote that in your question. What I'm saying is, SO is a Q&A network that works best for short programming question. If your question requires a lot of effort, you should consider adding a bounty. If you don't minimize your question nor add a bounty I doubt anybody will answer you